# div css onclick change multiple images

Tags: javascript, css, html, hyperlink

So I am trying to have four small images next to each other. Each of them are links with a background image url 100x100. So let's say initially they are all gray. When I hover over one of them, they get color (new image). Also, when I click on one of the images all the other images besides that one reset to the original gray scale image except the one I clicked

**Example:**

```
Gray1 Gray2 Gray3 Gray4
```

**Hover gray 2**

```
Gray1 Color2 Gray3 Gray4
```

**Click gray 2**

```
Gray1 Color2 Gray3 Gray4
```

**Hover gray4**

```
Gray1 Color2 Gray3 Color4
```

I know how to do a hover function. But how do I make all the other images "reset" onclick? Do i need to use javascript? Can I do this with just css?

Comment: I've made a simple implementation of that. Look at the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can only be achieved by using JavaScript. You have to cycle thru all 4 images and set them to grey if they are not the clicked image.

I have implemented this only with colors with jquery. You may have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/kaUWC/

Comment: It can be achieved with CSS I think, you just need to use a hidden radio button and the `:checked` pseudo-class.

Comment: The way you had it implemented means that if you hover over an `a` tag it will change colour, but if you don't click on one it stays the colour and you can end up with all coloured. Check out my edit http://jsfiddle.net/kaUWC/3/ this should work the way you need. And it reduces the amount of js. (Good thing!)

Comment: Then I misunderstood the OP. He said, when click on one, all other should go grey. This would make no scene if they go grey on mouse leave, because none other will be colored then, or I'm wrong?

Comment: @anothersrubery You're right. I just stated it is possible with CSS.